# Xdebug Problem: Superglobals seems unstable. Under some circumstances they will show contents, in others none

Tags: php, xdebug

I am building a website where I will use a posted value, if it's there. If not I will use another value. I use `isset($_POST[SomeIndex])` to check, but it always returns false.

Since I can work around it fairly easily, I do not plan to reinstall my Apache, Xdebug or VSCode, but it still worries me a bit. Does anyone know about cases like this?

[image: As you can see, Xdebug shows contradictory values]

Anyone heard about this? Or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: You should enclose the keys in quotes, else PHP tries to figure out it is a constant using its value. When not found, fallback to its string's name.

Comment: Missing the quotes around the keys will even throw a fatal (Uncaught Error: undefined constant) from PHP 8 and up.

Comment: What are you getting when you put $_POST in WATCH?

Comment: Markus Zeller: I use constants equal to its name. Ie. AConstant = "AConstant".

Comment: M.Eriksson: That seems very strange. What do they use the const reserved word for? I mean, if you cannot use constanst by entering the name.

Comment: Karnal-YK: 
$_POST: array(1)
  tagnr: “?10?10”
$_POST[0]: null
$_POST[tagnr]: “?10?10”
$_POST[tagnr][0]: “?”
$_POST[“GruppeId”]: null